# capital regain in investment

Tags: probability

If I invest in a commodity say x, whose value is $2000, and its value increases everyday by few or hundred dollars.

Suppose that when the price of the commodity was $2000 ,

I invested in it with $100.

Now after few days, I have total earning of $132,

so, if I take out my initial investment of $100,

and keep that $32

for further profits, will I make the same profit with $100 or it will be less ?

I don't understand the concept of the shares and market.

Comment: Obviously you make more if you invest more...is that what you are asking?  Assuming the asset goes up, that is.   If it goes down then you lose more.  Best to think of Profit/Loss as a percentage of Invested Amount.

Comment: I want to know if I remove the initial capital as soon as the profit starts coming, will I be getting profit based on initial investment(even if i have removed it) or will i be getting more according to $132.?

Comment: Of course you don't get any investment return (either positive or negative) on funds that are no longer invested!

Comment: I have the $32 still in the account!

Comment: Yes...and you will therefore earn the investment return on $\$32$.  But you do not get the return on the money you withdrew.  Suppose the asset went down to $0$...would you expect them to come to your house to demand the other $\$100$ back?

Comment: So initially you invested $\$100$ into a commodity with price $\$2000$, so you own $\$100/\$2000 = 1/20$ unit of that commodity. After a few days, the commodity price rises to $\$2000 \times \$132/\$100 = \$2640$. The amount of commodity you owned is unchanged - it is still $1/20$ unit and if you sell it all, you will obtain $\$132$ in return. Now in order to obtain $\$100$, you sell $1/20 \times \$100/\$132 = 5/132$ units of that commodity, and retain $1/20 - 5/132 = 2/165$ units of that commodity. You may still take profit based on the remaining $2/165$ units.

Comment: So what is better to keep the initial investment and let the profit come on it, or because of market risk, i should withdraw the initial investment and let interest come on the some amount that has already come as a profit ?

Answer (score 0):

[Shares](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shares.asp) are units of ownership interest in a corporation or financial asset.

Similarly, A [Commodity](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/commodity.asp) is a basic good used in commerce that is interchangeable with other commodities of the same type.

For any assets, in both cases the current value of a unit of share|commodity is taken with reference with its value at a given past time.

Lets have a asset "X", with initial value $x_0$ at the instant $t_0$. Today, the asset will have a current value $x(t)$. The number $x$ is the value of the asset, published at every Stock Exchange in the world and being updated at every time.

If you buy $a$ units at time $t$, you will have invested|spent $ax(t)$.

If you sell $a$ units at time $t+\Delta t$, you will have retired $ax(t+\Delta t)$.

Hence, the simple maths is your final earn is $a(x(t)-x(t+\Delta))$. Earning before commissions, interests, taxes, depreciation, amortization....

In your example, if the initial price of the commodity was x(t)=\$2000, you invested a(t)=\$100 and retired a(t+k)=\$132, then the commodity value when retiring is x(t+k)=\$2000 1.32=\$2640.

Hence the maximum return rate depends on the difference $x(t)-x(t+\Delta t)$ between the initial position and the final position.